# PHP- set background in php

Tags: php

i try to set color code but i cant

how can i set color bacground to the next code ?

can u help me please ?

```
<li class="tribe-events-list-widget-events <?php tribe_events_event_classes() ?>">

    <?php do_action( 'tribe_events_list_widget_before_the_event_title' ); ?>
    <!-- Event Title -->
    <h4 class="entry-title summary" >
        <a href="<?php echo tribe_get_event_link(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    </h4>

    <?php do_action( 'tribe_events_list_widget_after_the_event_title' ); ?> 
    <!-- Event Time -->

    <?php do_action( 'tribe_events_list_widget_before_the_meta' ) ?>

    <div class="duration">
        <?php echo tribe_events_event_schedule_details(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'tribe_events_list_widget_after_the_meta' ) ?>


</li>
```

Comment: `Set background colour in php` ... You need to be able to differentiate between HTML, CSS, PHP etc...

Answer (score 0):

add style attribute to your li tag:

```
style = 'background-color:red'
```